# How to display list of nodes by number in views

Tags: views, 8

I want to put my custom list of ids to views filter but is seems to work only for one id. How can I do it for this list for example (1, 5, 9, 12, 455)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter operator for regular expressions and this regex:

```
1|5|9|12|455
```

Comment: And how can I make manual order for those nodes ?

Comment: Add a sort criteria `Content: ID (ascending)` to order the nodes the way you've specified. For an arbitrary order a View wouldn't be the right tool, because it uses SQL queries. You can try a custom block type with an entity reference field for nodes, which gives you a drag and drop sortable list, but there are many other ways depending on the use case. Ask a different question.